# Unexpected namespace prefix app in child view of CustomLayout

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I got the error when use attribute in child view of a `CustomLayout` (I have define a custom LayoutParams to allow child view use this attribute)

[image]

However, code's still **RUNNING** and display correct value (you can check my code below, when I run app it will display "Hello" in logcat)

Here is my code
**style.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomRelativeLayout_Layout">
     <attr name="title" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**CustomRelativeLayout class**

```
public class CustomRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet attrs) {
        return new CustomLayoutParams(getContext(), attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAdded(View child) {
        super.onViewAdded(child);
        CustomLayoutParams layoutParams = (CustomLayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        Log.i("TAG", "title = " + layoutParams.title);
    }

    final class CustomLayoutParams extends RelativeLayout.LayoutParams {
        String title;

        CustomLayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(c, attrs);
            TypedArray ta =
                    c.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomRelativeLayout_Layout);
            title = ta.getString(R.styleable.CustomRelativeLayout_Layout_title);
            ta.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, I can disable it by add `tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"` but I don't like this much. Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Here is my demo https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/AndroidPassAttributeToChildVIew

Comment: have you tried adding `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in your custom layout root?

Comment: @Sagar yes, I have it in the root layout (`ConstraintLayout`). I just include it to my question

Comment: In that case, I can only think of changing `TextView` to `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView`

Comment: @Sagar you are right, I just test, when I use `AppCompatTextView` the error gone. However, it still have a problem, in my case I want to use many type of view which don't have AppCompat like `LinearLayout`, `RecyclerView`, ...

Comment: @Sagar I found a solution for my problem, its quite interesting, hope it help

Answer (score 5):

After many try, I found a solution for my problem

Change `title` to `layout_title` will make the error gone

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomRelativeLayout_Layout">
     <attr name="title" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

The **magic** is `layout_` because the error still happened if I use like
`title_`, `title_dasdasdsad`, `lo_title`, `title_23232`

Comment: Indeed, prefixing the attributes with layout_ does the trick. Tnx!